# Adding popup description to custom JSF tags in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets

I have a list of custom JSF tags, declared in an xml file in the following format:

[image: 1]

I'd like to provide the developers documentation for these tags that shows up in eclipse like the one for the builtin JSF tags.

[image: 2]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using a **WAAAAY** more current taglib... a 2.2 one would be good...

```
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2"
>
```

Then you'll notice (via code completion) that inside the `<tag>` elements you can add a `<documentation>`

See e.g. https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6.4/src/main/resources/META-INF/omnifaces-ui.taglib.xml